# Pointers lose reference when constructor exits

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constructor

Below is a constructor for forming a uniform grid of cubes (`cells`) and storing each `cell`'s neighbor within a vector.

The problem is that when I put a breakpoint at the end of the constructor, all of the references in the `neighbors` vector point to valid cells with correctly initialized values (`b` = 5). However, when the constructor exits, everything within the `neighbors` vector becomes uninitialized and points to what I assume is nothing (`b` = negative infinity). However, the `cell` itself (that holds the `neighbors` vector) is still properly initialized with the correct values.

The size of the `neighbors` vector also stays correct when the constructor exits. It just seems to lose the references to the cells for some reason.

CellGrid Header file (methods excluded for brevity)

```
class CellGrid {
public:
    CellGrid();
    CellGrid(int width, int height, int depth);
    ~CellGrid();

    int w;
    int h;
    int d;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>> cells;
};
```

CellGrid constructor part starts here

```
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
            cells[i][j][k] = Cell();
            cells[i][j][k].neighbors.reserve(27);
            cells[i][j][k].particles.reserve(8);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
            for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
                for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
                    for (int z = -1; z < 2; z++) {
                        if (i + x >= 0 && i + x < w && j + y >= 0 && j + y < h && k + z >= 0 && k + z < d) {
                            cells[i][j][k].addNeighbor(cells[i + x][j + y][k + z]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cell Struct:

```
struct Cell {
    std::vector<Particle*> particles;
    std::vector<Cell*> neighbors;
    int b = 5;

    void addParticle(Particle &p) {
        particles.push_back(&p);
    }

    void addNeighbor(Cell &c) {
        neighbors.push_back(&c);
    }
};
```

Comment: That's far from the usually required [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly is `cells`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. It is at the top of the snippet from the constructor now.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but in `Cell::addNeighbor` you are pushing the address of a parameter which is invalid once the method returns.

Comment: @Diego Not really, notice that the parameter is passed by reference.

Comment: Please show your class declaration and the constructor in full. It is very likely that you are filling up some local variables in the constructor which gets destroyed.

Comment: Can you post a complete example, please? Might have to do with what happens with `cells`.

Comment: You probably want `cells[i][j][k] = new Cell();`

Comment: @MarkkuK. Since the `std::vector` holds objects and not pointers, most definitely not.

Comment: Here is the complete constructor. I don't want to include it above because I think it would make the question impossible to read. http://pastebin.com/dNddiHhb

Comment: @Kinru You're not asked to add more code, but to reduce the existing one to a minimal reproducable sample (and post it into your question), that every one can check for the errors you actually get.

Comment: Now we just need a `main()` which will demonstrate the errors you're getting.

Comment: The method that calls the CellGrid constructor simply does this. At this point the problem described above occurs.
CellGrid grid = CellGrid((int)width, (int)height, (int)depth);

Comment: As Angew said, I'm passing it in by reference so shouldn't that not be a problem?

Comment: @crashmstr: "Taking the address" of a reference in fact takes the address of the refered-to object (which isn't local). Kinru is right.

Comment: Since you have a breakpoint and are debugging this, could you check if the *value of the address* is changing (i.e. *where* the pointer is pointing to), or whether the contents at that location are simply changing.

Comment: @Kinru, specifically, note: a- the **locations** of some of the cells (say, cells[0][0][0]) at the end of the constructor, b- the value of its pointers at the end of the constructor, c- the location of cells[0][0][0] after the constructor, and d- the value of its pointers after the constructor.

Comment: @EyasSH: So I just checked and the locations are the same, but the value of b is different. Not sure what you mean by value of pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug into [your project](https://github.com/JAGJ10/PositionBasedFluids/tree/master/PositionBasedFluids) for a little while to find the issue.  Though the problem exposes itself as the pointers becoming invalidated because of the vector changing, it's one step removed.  The code causes a problem because you are copying an entire `CellGrid` at the end of your `ParticleSystem` constructor.  When copied, a new vector is created with all of the cells, but their neighbor pointers refer to the `CellGrid` that was copied from.  The offending code:

```
ParticleSystem::ParticleSystem(float deltaT)   
{    
    this->deltaT = deltaT;    

    // ...a bunch of for loops...

    grid = CellGrid((int)width, (int)height, (int)depth);    
}
```

What you should do instead is construct `grid` in the initialization list

```
ParticleSystem::ParticleSystem(float deltaT)
    : deltaT{deltaT},
    grid(width, height, depth)
{    
    this->deltaT = deltaT;    

    // ...a bunch of for loops...
}
```

Further, you should delete the copy constructor and assignment operators from your `CellGrid` so this issue doesn't creep up somewhere else

```
class CellGrid {
  public:
    CellGrid();
    CellGrid(int width, int height, int depth);

    CellGrid(const CellGrid&) = delete;
    CellGrid& operator=(const CellGrid&) = delete;
   //...
};
```

This would have prevented the issue is the first place.

Another note is that your `CellGrid` value constructor is more complex than need be with regard to the resizing of vectors

```
CellGrid::CellGrid(int width, int height, int depth)
    : w{width},
    h{height},
    d{depth},
    cells(width, std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>(height, std::vector<Cell>(depth, Cell())))
{
    for (auto&& row : cells) {
        for (auto&& col : row ) {
            for (auto&& cell : col) {
                cell.neighbors.reserve(27);
                cell.particles.reserve(8);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
                for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
                    for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
                        for (int z = -1; z < 2; z++) {
                            if (i + x >= 0 && i + x < w && j + y >= 0 && j + y < h && k + z >= 0 && k + z < d) {
                                cells[i][j][k].addNeighbor(cells[i + x][j + y][k + z]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

since the width, height, and depth can be inferred from the vector dimensions, I'd also recommend taking out the variables and adding `width()`, `height()`, and `depth()` member functions to expose the dimensions.

A `CellGrid` probably shouldn't be default constructible.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you resize `cells` appropriately at every level, the following block of code results in out of bounds memory access, and results in undefined behavior.

```
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
            cells[i][j][k] = Cell();
            cells[i][j][k].neighbors.reserve(27);
            cells[i][j][k].particles.reserve(8);
        }
    }
}
```

What you need is:

```
cells.resize(w);
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    cells[i].resize(h);
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        cells[i][k].resize(d);
        for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
            // cells[i][j][k] = Cell(); <-- not needed; done by resize()
            cells[i][j][k].neighbors.reserve(27);
            cells[i][j][k].particles.reserve(8);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Earlier in the constructor (seen in the pastebin in the comments, but left out for brevity because I know for sure that it is correct) I resize the cells vector correctly.

Comment: @Kinru, you should post code exactly the way you have. Otherwise, you are wasting others' time.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying not to drown my question in code. I find it difficult to find the balance between too much and not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `cells` is declared in the constructor of `CellGrid`, is that so?

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>> cells;
```

This is problematic, because `cells` holds all `Cell` classes by value. When `cells` exists scope (which happens when the constructor returns, the `cells` variable is destructed, causing the contents of its vector (and nested vectors, and thus the `Cell` structs) to be destructed as well. Pointers to `Cell` objects therefore are invalid, and dereferencing them causes undefined behavior.

Instead, make `cells` a private member variable of `CellGrid`, doing so will keep the scope of `cells` (and thus the individual `Cell` structs) alive until the `CellGrid` itself is destructed.

Comment: This is what I get for trying to keep the code above as brief as possible. Cells is declared in the header file of the CellGrid.

Comment: @Kinru As brief as possible is fine, but it *must* remain *correct.* And *complete.*

Comment: Yea that is my fault. I have edited the original to include comments that should make it clearer. Sorry about that.

Comment: The edit is still not sufficient. Where/how is it declared in the header file? Try to include a minimal but complete example, i.e. type out the entire `CellGrid` declaration, clearing out irrelevant stub functions, etc.

Comment: Edited it again. Hope it is ok now?

Comment: @Kinru: A minimal example probably would be one-dimensional. You'd probably still have the out-of-bounds error that R Sahu pointed out.